# SQL Enrollment caps

Tags: sql

I am trying to show data from a table based on how many students are enrolled in each class on a second table.
Ex:

Table 1:

```
ClassID:  SLN:   Capacity:
1         ABCD       4
2         EFGH       20
3         IJKL       25
4         MNOP       20
5         QRST       25 
6         UVWX       25
```

Table 2:

```
StudentID:   Class:    
1             ABCD  
3             DCAB   
2             ABCD  
4             ABCD  
5             ABCD
6             EFGH
```

So the output I want is:

```
ClassID:  SLN:   Capacity:
2         EFGH       20
3         IJKL       25
4         MNOP       20
5         QRST       25
6         UVWX       25
```

So classes can appear in one table but not the other. I do not want the classes from table 2 that are not in table 1 but I do want the classes that are in table 1 and not table 2. I also do not want classes that are full to be shown. 
Thanks

Comment: there is not enough information to solve the problem.  We do not know what full means in this context, further your explanation of what you want isn't very clear.  You need to provide us with a SQL fiddle and more importantly this seems like homework.  Give us what you have tried and provide a clear issue that you need help with.

Comment: I've tried: USE Reinstatement
SELECT Distinct Classes.* 
FROM Classes INNER JOIN 
  (SELECT SCClass, count(SClassID) AS enrolled 
  FROM StudentClass GROUP BY SCClass) SubQuery 
  ON (SubQuery.enrolled < 4 )
(I used 4 here instead of capacity because there aren't enough people in each class to test the real capacities of 20 or 25)

Comment: Full means the number of students enrolled in each class is the same number as the capacity. I can't figure out how to only show the classes that aren't full from table 1 instead of showing all the classes from table 1

Comment: Right, but your comment about how many are in each class makes no sense.  It is not possible to deduce how many are enrolled in each class based on the schema you provided.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean... The way to tell how many are in each class is based off table 2. If more than one StudentID shares the same class then there are multiple people enrolled in the class. So in the example 4 people are enrolled in class ABCD, 1 in EFGH, and 1 in DCAB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding your requirements correct, I think you can use the following:

```
select t1.classid, t1.sln, t1.capacity
from table1 t1
where not exists (select 1  -- classes not in table2
                  from table2 t2
                  where t1.sln = t2.class)
  or t1.capacity > (select count(*)  -- classes where capacity not met
                    from table2 t2
                    where t1.sln = t2.class
                    group by class);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/468a9/6)